# Why do we need the colon (:) in the line string = string[:j] + ' ' + string[j+1:];

Tags: python, string

I am trying to understand why do we need the colon if I remove I get an error.
I am trying to understand more about strings

```
string = "welcome to the world of python programming";
    
print("Duplicate characters in a given string: ");  
for i in range(0, len(string)):  
    count = 1;  
    for j in range(i+1, len(string)):  
        if(string[i] == string[j] and string[i] != ' '):  
            count = count + 1;  
            string = string[:j] + ' ' + string[j+1:];  
    
    if(count > 1 and string[i] != '0'):  
        print(string[i]," - ",count)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because they mean very different things.  This is just Python syntax.

`string[j]` says "give me the one letter at index `j`".

`string[:j]` says "give me all of the letters up to but not including index `j`".

`string[j:]` says "give me all of the letters starting with index `j`".

This is called "slicing".  There are other options as well.

Comment: You might want to clarify that last point that it's the characters starting at index `j`, but ending only at the end of the string. And out of bounds indexes are allowed in slices, they just result in empty results.

Comment: And... of course there's SomeString[::j] which says lets "jump" to every j-th index and output that. (inclusive of the 0th element, of course), this is just extra to the colon syntax of python though...